# Opencv 3.0 with which Version of FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, ffmpeg

I can't seem to get OpenCV 3.0 to build properly with ffmpeg 2.7 or 2.4. Does anyone know which version works? I am running Mac OSX Yosemite. I seem to get linking errors when attempting to build opencv with ffmpeg support:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _avcodec_open2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _avcodec_open2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_lzma_code", referenced from:
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tiff.o)
  "_lzma_end", referenced from:
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tiff.o)
  "_lzma_stream_decoder", referenced from:
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tiff.o)
  "_swr_alloc", referenced from:
      _opus_decode_init in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
  "_swr_close", referenced from:
      _opus_decode_packet in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
      _opus_decode_flush in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
  "_swr_convert", referenced from:
      _opus_decode_packet in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
  "_swr_free", referenced from:
      _opus_decode_close in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
  "_swr_init", referenced from:
      _opus_decode_packet in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
  "_swr_is_initialized", referenced from:
      _opus_decode_packet in libavcodec.a(opusdec.o)
  "_x264_bit_depth", referenced from:
      _X264_init_static in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
      _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_encoder_close", referenced from:
      _X264_close in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_encoder_delayed_frames", referenced from:
      _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_encoder_encode", referenced from:
      _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_encoder_headers", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_encoder_open_142", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_encoder_reconfig", referenced from:
      _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_levels", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_param_apply_profile", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_param_default", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_param_default_preset", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_param_parse", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_x264_picture_init", referenced from:
      _X264_frame in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
  "_xvid_encore", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
      _xvid_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
      _xvid_encode_close in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
  "_xvid_global", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
  "_xvid_plugin_2pass2", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
      _ff_xvid_rate_control_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)
      _ff_xvid_rate_estimate_qscale in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)
      _ff_xvid_rate_control_uninit in libavcodec.a(libxvid_rc.o)
  "_xvid_plugin_lumimasking", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
  "_xvid_plugin_single", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
  "_xvid_plugin_ssim", referenced from:
      _xvid_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libxvid.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here are the flags which I compiled ffmpeg, maybe that could be the cause?:

./configure --prefix=~/Software/ffmpeg-2.4.10/ --enable-shared --enable-avresample --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-gpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those aren't ffmpeg (libavcodec, libavformat, libavutils, libswscale, etc.) linker errors. They're dependencies ffmpeg was built with: iconv, swresample (which is part of ffmpeg), lzma, x264, and xvid. You need to link to libiconv, libswresample, liblzma, libx264, and libxvid.

A particular version of ffmpeg isn't the problem here. The problem is that ffmpeg has some dependencies you need to link to.

You can `--enable-libx264` if you want, but you need to actually have libx264 on your machine for OpenCV/ffmpeg to be able to link to. Same with all the others.

Comment: So it looks like all except libiconv were already installed, but I am still getting the same linker errors. I will try to rebuild ffmpeg now to see if that resolves anything (now that I have libiconv installed)

Comment: So rebuilding ffmpeg after installing and verifying that the libraries you mentioned were in place and then attempting to rebuild opencv was unsuccessful--I still can't link against the libraries even though they are installed (using homebrew).

Comment: Welp, I think I just need to blow some directories away and now all is well. Thanks!